# Check a checkbox under a condition with Angular11

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I found many similar question but all of them are pretty old and i can t make it work on Angular 11

i have this checkbox:

```html
<p class="form-check-label">
  <input (change)="test($event.target.checked)" class="form-check-input"
    type="checkbox">My checkbox
</p>
```

The checkbox changes the value of a boolean from false to true and viceversa; if this boolean is true html shows some more content

Now my Typescript is changing the value of the boolean but the checkobx remains uncheked

Anything i can try?

Comment: Have you tried just binding to the checked attribute? `[checked]="myBooleanValue"`. You're probably better off looking into how Angular models or forms work though as this isn't a pattern you want to scale.

Comment: try to add value attribute: `[value]="my_value"`

Comment: TY @Alex it worked... didn't expected to be that easy honestly,